# Bookmark loads old version of web application

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, refresh, bookmarks

We have an Angular web app that we often update. We push a notification to all users that forces them to hard refresh their browser. This has always worked fine. However, we noticed that even when they can see the new and updated version of the website, when they navigate to it using their bookmark, it loads the old version. There's nothing funny in the underlying URL that I can see. Any experience with this?

Browser: Google Chrome [Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)]